# SharePoint 2010 Site Edit History

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise

I am working on a site and after returning from the weekend I noticed that a lot of changes were made. I am wondering is there a way to view the edit history of the site? I.e. is there a way to see who has edited the site (and what changes they have made, if possible)?

I want to be able to see who has edited the site so that I can manage permissions more effectively going forward, because this incident has caused me to lose a lot of time...

Comment: You should be able to check out the version history for your page. Navigate to Site Pages or Pages and check the version history for the current page for your site. You should be able to restore it to an earlier version as well to undo the changes.

Comment: And you could enable auditing for your site to log everything that is happening on the site, but be very careful with this feature as it can grow exceptionally fast and consume lots of diskspace. http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/sharepoint-server-help/configure-audit-settings-for-a-site-collection-HA102031737.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you want to view the edit history, both auditing and versioning can achieve your goal.

As versioning cannot record modifications in site level, a simple workaround is storing your web pages in the document libraries and enable versioning on document libraries.

So, I suggest you to enable auditing to monitor the site modification and use versioning to record the change history.

For more information, please refer to:

- [Configure auditing](http://blogs.interfacett.com/configuring-auditing-sharepoint-2010)
- [Configure audit settings for a site collection](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/configure-audit-settings-for-a-site-collection-HA102031737.aspx)
- [View audit log reports](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/view-the-version-history-of-an-item-or-file-in-a-list-or-library-HA101853104.aspx)
- [Maintaining versions of files or items](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointserver/CH101779681033.aspx)